# ngrx/effect how to parse params from a selector into a GET

Tags: angular, ngrx-store, ngrx-effects, ngrx-router-store

I m getting the Id and the ova from a Selected service selector and want to parse it into a GET method calling an API endpoint in the effect.
this is what I have done but on the selected service page load I'm getting null when I log the data. Need helps.

```
@Effect()
    loadService$ = this.actions$.ofType(servicesActions.LOAD_ONE_SERVICE)
    .pipe(        
        switchMap(() => {
            this.store.select(fromSelect.getSelectedService).subscribe(
                data => {
                    this.id = data.merchantId,
                    this. ova = data.ova
                }
            )
            return this.appservice
            .getServiceById(
                this.id,
                this.ova
            )
            .pipe(
                map(service => new servicesActions.LoadServiceSuccess(service)),
                catchError(error => of (new servicesActions.LoadServiceFail(error)))
            );
        })
    );
```

Comment: why don't you pass id and ova to LOAD_ONE_SERVICE instead of calling store inside effect

Comment: can you clarify it please @NitinWalia

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try something like this. Use the switchmap to keep one level of nesting in the pipe.

```
@Effect()
    loadService$ = this.actions$.ofType(servicesActions.LOAD_ONE_SERVICE)
    .pipe(
      withLatestFrom(this.store.select(fromSelect.getSelectedService)),
      switchMap(({merchantId, ova}) => this.appservice.getServiceById(merchantId, ova))
      .pipe(
        map(service => new servicesActions.LoadServiceSuccess(service)),
        catchError(error => of(new servicesActions.LoadServiceFail(error)))
      )         
    );
```

Comment: If Im not wrong, this will re-trigger the `getServiceById` call every time that the `fromSelect.getSelectedService` emits a new value,

Comment: You are correct as always Jota ;) use withLatestFrom to avoid that. I edited the response.

Comment: BTW, you should add pipe(map,catchError) to the service call, otherwise whenever the service call throws an error the effect stream will complete.

Comment: True, is a effect. What usually i do in the effects is return the original stream to don't do a pipe inside another. In this case I would use the catchError like this: 
catchError(error => { 
    new servicesActions.LoadServiceFail(error);
    return this. loadService$;
}). What do you think about this?